# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with dual boot Windows 10 hangs up with initrams

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have a **daily problem** with **dual boot OS**(windows 10, ubuntu 18.04). Always after windows 10 was turn off, **I can not boot into graphics mode of ubuntu 18.04**. The process hangs up on initrams. **But always happens again and again.** So I must always do it again. If I want to boot graphics mode ubuntu, use this command:

**fsck.ext4 -p -b 884736 -B 4096 /dev/sda5** On this disk I have installed ubuntu, its a root partition.

**fsck.ext4 -p -b 884736 -B 4096 /dev/sdd2** Here I have more data.

**What I can do ?** Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message please?

Comment: Have you installed a Windows 10 driver that allows you to read/write to ext4 partitions?

Comment: The complete error message I can not send. But ubuntu wrote a message about wrong block size for device /dev/sda5 ....etc. And I have installed on Windows 10 Ext2fsd software. Today I uninstaled this software and I think it will no more blocks running Ubuntu into graphics mode. Thank you for helping me.